# Passing Variables to ASPX to the URL String from AS3 - Message Failed

Tags: asp.net, actionscript-3, flash

Im trying to send three variables (fname, lname, and email) to append them to the URL string like this http://www.whatever.com?address=&firstname=&lastname=&email= and it traced as "Message Failed" I wonder what I did wrong with this code.

in Flash 'fname_txt', 'lname_txt', and 'email_txt' are the instance names of the Input Text

[image]

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.net.navigateToURL;

mcButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onClick);
function onClick(e:MouseEvent):void {
var scriptRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("../index.aspx");
var scriptLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
var scriptVars:URLVariables = new URLVariables();

scriptLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, handleLoadSuccessful);
scriptLoader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, handleLoadError);

scriptVars.fname = fname_txt.text;
scriptVars.lname = lname_txt.text;
scriptVars.email = email_txt.text;

scriptRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
scriptRequest.data = scriptVars;

scriptLoader.load(scriptRequest);

function handleLoadSuccessful($evt:Event):void
{
trace("Message sent.");
}

function handleLoadError($evt:IOErrorEvent):void
{
trace($evt); <----------------UPDATED
}

fname_txt.text = "";
lname_txt.text = "";
email_txt.text = "";

}
```

Comment: In your handleLoadError, you should trace the error message (given in the event). It'll you and us to see the kind of issue you have.

Comment: It showed 

[IOErrorEvent type="ioError" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2 text="Error #2032: Stream Error. URL: file:///Y|/Creative/projects/Banners/10130%20%2D%20MediaBuys%20%2D%20May%20%2D%2‌​0BannerAds%20%2D%20Flash/Creative/index.aspx"] 

after when I put trace($evt); Does that mean the aspx file is not found?

Comment: Error #2032 appears when the Flash Player couldn't load the file. It usually means that either the file was not found, or that the loading was block for security reasons (usually crossdomain issues). That said, I find strange that you use as url a local file path (file://Y:\Creative...) rather than a http url; does your aspx file works when you use this path ?

Comment: I changed the trace to trace(scriptVars); and it showed email=cluneborg%40hotmail%2Ecom&lname=Luneborg&fname=Christian - it looks like it working just fine and just need to create aspx file to receive the variables. Thanks!